# Is it okay to install floating shelves in a reinforced beam/column?

Tags: shelving, beam

So, this is the reinforced concrete beam and column. Was wondering if it will cause any problems on the building if I installed floating shelves in them.

And in the case that there are water/electric lines inside, I’m guessing the screw won’t penetrate that deep? Assuming that they’re in the center.

Thanks in advance!
[image]

Comment: don't assume anything and don't guess

Comment: Is this your house or is it a condo? Try and obtain drawings for it.

Comment: The column and maybe the the beam look to be over size.  I would expect to find electrical, plumbing, HVAC also inside.  The cement beam and column probably half the size you see outside.  So a drywall/plaster wall covering them and hiding stuff.

Comment: That doesn't look like concrete to me. It looks like the beams and columns are boxed in. Probably with drywall, maybe some other way. How do you know it's concrete behind the surface covering? Do you know how it's held on, EG metal studs? What do you plan to use the floating shelves for - anything heavy?

Comment: Do you own this space or are you renting it?  In rentals of uncertain construction my answer to questions like this is always that the floor is an easy way to provide great support to everything.